# Strategy for merging by intervals in PANDAS

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two dataframes with different data and a common column BH.

TABLE A

| BH | litho | from m | to m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | clay | 0 | 5 |
| S1 | gravel | 5 | 10 |
| S1 | something | 10 | 12 |

TABLE B

| BH | sample | from m | to m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | c1 | 2 | 2.5 |
| S1 | c2 | 11 | 11.5 |

I would like to retrieve the litho value from table A into B according to the position of my sample

I need an output like this

| BH | sample | from m | to m | litho |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | c1 | 2 | 2.5 | clay |
| S1 | c2 | 11 | 11.5 | something |

What would be the best strategy for merging TABLE A into TABLE B?